# Query relatedTo category or empty field

Tags: craft4, relatedto

I'm not able to query a list of items relatet to a category or if category field is empty in the same query. I have to make two and merge them.

Is it not possible?

**This works:**

```
{# Fetch entries related to the specified category #}
{% set relatedDetails = plan.policyDetails
                              .relatedTo({ targetElement: block.category.one(), field: 'category' })
                              .type('customPolicy')
                              .all() %}
        
{# Fetch entries without any category assigned #}
{% set unassignedDetails = plan.policyDetails.category(':empty:').all()%}
                              
        
{# Combine the two sets of entries #}
{% set customDetails = relatedDetails|merge(unassignedDetails)|unique %}
```

**This does not work (does not include entries that has empty category field):**

```
{% set customDetails = plan.policyDetails
    .relatedTo([
        'or',
        { targetElement: block.category.one(), field: 'category' },
        { targetElement: ':empty:', field: 'category' } // Check for empty category
    ])
    .type('customPolicy')
    .all() %}
```